# Открытие необходимой формы из нескольких

Tags: c#

Вызываю форму номенклатур (одна форма для нескольких таблиц) таким образом:

```
private void miCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new MyContext();
            db.Customers.Load();
            var customers = db.Customers.Local.ToBindingList();
            var fNomenclature = new FormNomenclature(customers);
            fNomenclature.Text = "Заказчики";
            fNomenclature.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Появляется форма номенклатур:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код формы номенклатур:

```
public partial class FormNomenclature : Form
{        
    public FormNomenclature(object dbSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        dgvNomenclature.DataSource = dbSet;
    }

}
```

Далее по кнопке Добавить/Изменить должна появиться следующая форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма добавления и изменения будет у каждой таблицы своя.
Как не используя IF ELSE и CASE, открывать мне нужную форму добавления и изменения номенклатуры?

Comment: Привязывать обработчики событий при создании формы

Comment: а можно поконкретней, что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

```
кнопкаДобавить.Клик += событие_появления_Формы_Добавить
```

Такая же конструкция и для кнопки изменить, или использовать конструкцию издатель/подписчик.